# How would one apporach this

Tags: mysql, select, join, insert

Say I have tableA that looks something like this:

```
colA | colB | colC | colD | 
 1   |  x   |  5   |   v  |
 2   |  y   |  2   |   r  |
 3   |  z   |  4   |   t  | 
 4   |  e   |  8   |   p  |
 5   |  n   |  1   |   m  |
 6   |  f   |  3   |   i  |
 7   |  es  |  8   |   pw |
 8   |  ne  |  5   |   ms |
 9   |  fd  |  3   |   ir |
 10  |  u   |  9   |   gv |
 11  |  y   |  1   |   rh |
 12  |  w   |  4   |   en |
```

and so on ( for around 80,000 rows).....

And I want to fill tableB with data from tableA like this

```
colA | colB | colC | colD | colE | colF | colG|
 2   |   x  |   v  |   y  |   r  |   z  |   t | 
 5   |   e  |   p  |   n  |   m  |   f  |   i |
 11  |   u  |   gv |   y  |   rh |   w  |  en |
```

and so on (for around 10,000 rows).....

As you can see,rows from tableA where tableA.colD<=2 have been used as a reference to generate the new rows in tableB.

The row above where tableA.colD<=2 occupies tableB.(colB,colC), the row below where tableA.colD<=2 occupies tableB.(colF,colG) and the row where tableA.colD<=2 occupies tableB.(colD,colE) with tableA.colA where tableA.colD<=2 being used as an id in tableB.colA

I suspect a combination of joins, inserts and updates are in order but I have no idea how to go about such a task. Using the following, I can copy the rows as a range to a temp table but that's as far as I get :/

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cant_work_it_out()
BEGIN
SET @final = (select colA from tableA where colD<=2 order by colA desc limit 1);
SET x=0;
REPEAT 
SET @centre = (select colA from tableA where colD<=2 order by colA asc limit x,1);
INSERT INTO temptable 
(select * from tableA where colA= @centre order by colA asc limit 1)
union  
(select * from tableA where colA < @centre order by colA desc limit 1)
union 
(select * from tableA where colA > @centre order by colA asc limit 1);
x=x+1;
UNTIL @centre=@final
END REPEAT
END $$
```

Any ideas how I go about rearranging the data as described above?

EDIT: this is not a problem of collapsing every three rows. The rows to be collapsed will always occur around a central row where colD<=2

Comment: Maybe I need another cup of coffee, but I can't see how you've generated Table B from Table A.

Comment: @Mike, there is a 3 row range selected from tableA and reorganised into a single row in tableB. The range is centred around row where colD<=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, i completely misunderstood what you actually try to achieve, but i'll give it a shot. I have left out the selection and insertion within the loop, since you already managed to do that yourself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE possible_to_work_it_out()
BEGIN
SET @start = (SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE (colA+1)%3=0 ORDER BY colA ASC LIMIT 1);
SET @final = (SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE (colA+1)%3=0 ORDER BY colA DESC LIMIT 1);
SET @center=@start;
REPEAT 
INSERT INTO temptable 
[...]
@center = @center + 3;
UNTIL @center=@final+3
END REPEAT
END $$
```

What i understood from the short sample of your tables is that you group every 3 rows of tableA together into a single row of tableB. So you just have to select the first and last triple and then increment from start to end in steps of 3. Whether the selection of start and end actually depends on it being (start+1)%3=0 or any other condition is of course completely up to you. Beware: this looping through tableA assumes, your colA has no gaps in it!

If i have misunderstood your question, please give so more details. It's not easy to see the pattern from such short samples.

---

Edit after your comment: (the code should be self explanatory)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE possible_to_work_it_out()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTable AS (SELECT colA, colD FROM tableA)

SET @center = (SELECT colA FROM tempTable ORDER BY colA ASC LIMIT 1);

REPEAT 
@prev = SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE colA < @center ORDER BY colA DESC LIMIT 1;
@next = SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE colA > @center ORDER BY colA ASC LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO tableB 
(SELECT [...] FROM tableA WHERE colA=@prev)
UNION
(SELECT [...] FROM tableA WHERE colA=@center)
UNION
(SELECT [...] FROM tableA WHERE colA=@next);

@center = SELECT FROM tempTable WHERE colA > @center ORDER BY colA ASC LIMIT 1;
UNTIL @center = NULL
END REPEAT

END $$
```

But take care: i could not test that right now, it's just the algorithm. Please check especially the details of creating a temporary table and the return of the last select statement, since i just do not know exactly how mysql behaves.
Creating a temporary table with just the indexes and then selecting the adjacent rows is forgiving to gaps in colA. Increases the load on the database system but that should not be too much of a problem with only 80k rows.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Sorry for the short examples. I thought in this case shorter was better.
As you can hopefully see from the edit in the sample tables, not every block of three will be collapsed into tableB. 
The block must have at it's centre a row with colD<=2. 
Could you explain this to me a little please: (colA+1)%3=0
Also, maybe I can't see it, but where are the rows collapsed in your answer?

Comment: Yes, ColA is continuous, but just to make things intersting, in the real tables, it is actually filled with datetime values

Comment: @user3180258 (colA+1)%3=0 means that colA plus 1 must be a multiple of 3. "%" is the modulo operator and returns the remainder of an integer division. I removed it from the second algorith, since you could not use it with DATEs, it just works with ints.

Comment: I thought maybe a little sleep would help me understand better. But it seems I still can't see where the three rows are collapsed into a single row. Doesn't UNION just stack the rows on top of one another?